# apache django Bad Request 400 debug=True

Tags: python, linux, django, apache, request

I'm trying to run Django 1.6 project with virtualenv on Apache/2.4.9 (Python 2.7.4 installed).
I've setup Debug=True to avoid host conflict. All the time I gets 400 bad request.

The problem occures only on my local server ( Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.11.0-19-generic x86_64) ). I deployed project on other server ( Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-27-generic x86_64) | Apache/2.4.7) and all works fine.

Below vhost configuration.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName myproject_django.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject_django

    RequestHeader set X-Request-Start "%t"

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myproject_django/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject_django user=user group=user processes=5 threads=25 python-path=/var/www/myproject_django/myproject:/var/www/myproject_django/myproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject_django

    SetEnv SERVER_TYPE REGULAR

    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    <Directory /var/www/myproject_django>
            #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            #AllowOverride None
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/myproject_django/myproject/myproject/static/

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/myproject-error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
    #LogLevel warn
    LogLevel error

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/myproject-access.log combined
```

If you need more indormation please let me know.

EDIT:

Can it be connected to haproxy or DNS server?

EDIT2 (issue resolved):
The problem was with "_" char in ServerName (Django issue)

Comment: If it's only on your local, why not just use the development server?

Comment: And shouldn't the `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` values be `/var/www/myproject_django/myproject`?